# SSL: Two DNS Names, 1 IP, 2 certs - Java only sees 1 and complains

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have an Apache mapped to two external DNs:

```
sub1.dn.com
sub2.dn.com
```

That both map to the same IP.

Each has its own SSL cert.  Each cert shows the CN and SAN as-is and matching (i.e. sub1.dn.com for sub1 and the same for sub2).

But, when my Java code tries to connect to, say, **sub2.dn.com**
it fails, with:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alte
rnative DNS name matching **sub2.dn.com** found.

Enabling the Java SSL debug output shows something odd- it seems that Java downloads and uses the other (sub1) cert!!

```
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: **sub1.dn.com**
]
```

So it seems that browsers are happy, and get the right cert. But Java always sees the sub1.dn.com cert, never the other.  So it clearly doesn't match when sub2 is called.

Any ideas why Java would do this?  And perhaps how to fix it! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two HTTPS domains on the same IP running the client requires support for SNI ([Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) for selecting the correct certificate. Note that SNi can only work with TLS, SSL is not supported.

[Java 7 has SNI support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html), therefore you should check if you using a current Java version.

On server side make sure that TLS is supported and the preferred protocol.